# Update table inner join with 3rd table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Fact_Actuals yable with a new column "Segment_Id".

I need to insert the segment id from DimsegmentMaster into Fact_Actuals.

Link is with SegmentMaster and Source Table column.

Link is with FactTable is Measures of the Source Table column below.

Kindly provide me the update query, as my below query is not fine.

```
UPDATE Application_DB.[cdw].[Fact_Actuals] 
  set segment_sid =
  (SELECT c.SID
   FROM Application_DB.[cdw].[Fact_Actuals] b
   inner join Source_DB.STA.SourceTable a
     ON  convert(decimal(20,10),LTRIM(RTRIM(a.[K308]))) = b.NetExternalSales
     and convert(decimal(20,10),LTRIM(RTRIM(a.[K203]))) = b.Quantity_CON
     and convert(decimal(20,10),LTRIM(RTRIM(a.[K202]))) = b.Quantity_KG
   inner join Application_DB.cdw.DimSegmentMaster c
     ON RTRIM(a.[C005])=c.SegmentOriginal
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE b  
set segment_sid = c.sid
FROM Application_DB.[cdw].[Fact_Actuals] b
inner join Source_DB.STA.SourceTable a
ON 
    convert(decimal(20,10),LTRIM(RTRIM(a.[K308])))=b.NetExternalSales
    and convert(decimal(20,10),LTRIM(RTRIM(a.[K203])))=b.Quantity_CON
    and convert(decimal(20,10),LTRIM(RTRIM(a.[K202])))=b.Quantity_KG
inner join Application_DB.cdw.DimSegmentMaster c
ON RTRIM(a.[C005])=c.SegmentOriginal
```